# php socket daemon, 2nd window tab not being processed until broadcast is sent out

Tags: php, sockets

So I have written a daemon in php and it worked great until I opened two tabs in the same browser and then this error started happening. The 2 tabs were treated as the same socket because when a message is sent the first tab gets the message but the 2nd doesnt until another message is sent. So if 3 tabs are open it alternates between the 3. Is there any way to solve this?

Links to Daemon and Client:
[Daemon](http://syphic.com/z.daemon.php.txt)
[Client](http://syphic.com/z.client.php.txt)
Command Line: php z.daemon.php

Just 2 tabbed windows: client.php?action=listen
Then run: client.php?action=broadcast&broadcast=test

-- Edit --
Also, the 2nd tab window which is listen does not even show its connected as a client in the commandline output.

-- Edit --
Basically is there a way to send unique ids to socket_select to help it figure out if its a new or not?

Answer (score 0):

Genreate an random id on page load and use that to identify the individual clients with the query string.

Comment: How can I do that and have socket_select identify to it? because the 2nd tab window is not even displaying that it is connected in the commandline output notes.

Comment: Why not package up the ID with the serialized data? and programaticaly decide when to return responses to the appropriate client in the daemon.

Comment: I would if the daemon showed when the 2nd tab connected. It doesnt even show that the 2nd connected so I can not attach something to it.